# Time travel movie - travelling in a lift

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

Remember only bits and pieces. There is a lift and a key to it. Instead of pressing the floor number, a year is pressed and the lift will travel to that period (example - 1936). There is a girl who got this key from an old man. She travels to different time periods. She finds another girl in some old fashioned house, befriends her and she is brought to the new world with her. The old time girl is stunned by seeing the huge buildings and traffic. Guess it was a movie. Not sure if it was a series!

Comment: How interesting. I've never heard of this film but once I had a dream where I travelled to the future using a lift, and the button for a higher floor took me to a later year.

Comment: @GeorgeT - I'm guessing you feel asleep while watching this film. Did you also dream that you were a photogenic 14 year old girl?

Comment: The movie *Time at the Top* is based on a book of the same name by Edward Ormondroyd. First published in 1963.

Comment: @Richard: I've still never watched it, so no. It was also all about aliens. :p

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're describing the 1999 film; "[Time at the Top](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0160986/)".

> 14-year old Susan Shawson travels back in time in her building's
>   elevator. As altered by a retired physicist living in her building, it
>   transports her from Philadelphia of 1998 back to the same place in
>   1881. There she meets Victoria Walker, a girl her own age in need of assistance with her own family problems. Gradually discovering the
>   power of her time machine, Susan, Victoria, and her young brother
>   Robert travel back and forth in time and succeed in changing both the
>   past and the future.

One of the key features of the film is a time-travelling elevator. The scene of Victoria being surprised by traffic is at 1:08:00